# How do I run two isolated instances of firefox?

Tags: firefox, ubuntu

For testing purposes, I want to install two different instances of firefox on ubuntu - so that they don't share cookies.
(I want to simultaneously login with both instances as different users to our website). 
How do I do that?
I do it with Firefox & Opera, but I prefer Firefox (because of firebug).

Comment: You accepted the wrong answer to what's being asked. Also check: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Opening_a_new_instance_of_Firefox_with_another_profile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [profile argument](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments) like this:

```
firefox -profile "E:\myprofile"
```

Sorry about the windows file path ;) If you copy your main profile to a different profile, you will be starting a separate instance.

Comment: NO! Contrary to the common sense, it will not launch **separate** firefox instance. E.g. you would still be able to shut down both windows with `Ctrl+Q`. Use `firefox -new-instance -p "E:\myprofile` instead.

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski Something might have changed. With `78.10.0esr` shipped with openSUSE Leap-15.2, `firefox  -P <profile>` with a *different* profile, is enough to run another instance, `Ctrl+Q` does not quit other profiles. In other words, profiles seem isolated from one another.

Answer (score 25):

There's also one more possibility. You can execute the `firefox` command like:

```
firefox -P "profile-name" -no-remote
```

The option `-no-remote` disables remote control (i.e. control using the `firefox` command) of the new instance and logically it also implies the option `-new-instance` which is required to run a new isolated instance. It is also possible to use only the option `-new-instance`:

```
firefox -P "profile-name" -new-instance
```

### Creating a new profile

```
firefox -ProfileManager -new-instance
```

The command will open an interactive window where you can manage existing profiles and create new ones. You can also start a new instance of Firefox using a selected profile. Be careful of the option "*Use the selected profile without asking at startup*" which is selected by default and which will make the selected profile to be the default one being used when starting `firefox` without `-P`.

### Help

Excerpt from `firefox -help`:

```
  -P <profile>       Start with <profile>.
  -ProfileManager    Start with ProfileManager.
  -no-remote         Do not accept or send remote commands; implies -new-instance.
  -new-instance      Open new instance, not a new window in running instance.
```

Comment: I think that should be -P instead of -p.

Comment: Better yet: Use `firefox -new-instance -p` or `firefox -new-instance -p <profile name>`. This is explicit way how to do it, according to `firefox -help`.

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski This is just a different way which implies `-new-instance`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Multifox](http://br.mozdev.org/multifox/) extension in order to have two separate instances of Firefox that do not share cookies, but by still using only one profile.

Comment: This add-on is extremely useful. In the past I was using multiple profiles but now I am using just the add-on. In most cases I need just a different set of cookies. --- With this add-on it is very easy to create a new multifox profile just for a temporary use (like lab testing or labs on a training) and delete it after few days.

Answer (score 3):

Make two users on ubuntu

user1
user2

Login as user1
start Firefox1

start some sort of terminal and ssh -X user2@host

start Firefox2

Or, did you mean two different versions of Firefox, say 3.x and 2.x?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.command-tab.com/2008/06/18/how-to-run-firefox-2-and-3-simultaneously/

I believe that the URL above will help you.  It is in relation to running FF2 and FF3 at the same time and as separate instances.

The above describes windows and mac but the concept is the same no matter what the OS.  Upon installation don't merely allow it to go into the same old fire fox folder, give it a unique path.  Then, in Firefox create a profile for each.

Answer (score 1):

If you need just two instances of firefox, you can use *New Private Window*

to run second instance. (use <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> as a shortcut)

Comment: Sadly this seems to be wrong. If I login at facebook, open a "New Private Window" and open facebook, I'm in my account, too. But in a private window, no history is saved etc.

Answer (score 1):

In linux terminal run,

`firefox -new-instance -P "Another Profile"`

Then create new profile > start firefox.

It opens new instance, not a new window in running instance, which allows multiple copies of application to be open at a time.

From next time `firefox -new-instance -P <Profile name>`

Source:  mozilla [website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options)