# How to run Multiple Instances of Firefox in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, firefox, ubuntu-14.04

I have a `.sh` script which is something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
  firefox ://imacros/?m=script.iim & sleep 600
  killall firefox
  sleep 5
done
```

But I wanted to run two Firefox instances and made this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
  firefox ://imacros/?m=script.iim
  firefox ://imacros/?m=script2.iim & sleep 600
  killall firefox
  sleep 5
done
```

But even now, only 1 instance of Firefox starts with the first script running.

I want to know how can I run 2 instances at a time with both doing different tasks?

Comment: Having a bash script doesn't mean you have a programming problem. You have a Firefox usage problem. Please read [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options).

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [How do I run two isolated instances of firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613917/how-do-i-run-two-isolated-instances-of-firefox)

Answer (score 3):

Firefox has an option for that: `firefox --no-remote` ;)

Basically, `--no-remote` forbids firefox to try and communicate with other firefox' instances ; I use it when I need two firefox windows with different profiles.

[Documenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Multiple_Firefox_Profiles)

Answer (score 1):

You can run firefox from different users having different home directories. Then you may have as many instances as many you need.

Comment: I tried that...Thanks but it's not working i am currently trying this :
firefox -a firefox -remote "OpenURL('http://your.homepage.here',new-window)"

Comment: May be then you could try another firefox profile: `firefox -P new ...`. I am not sure whether this requires to have some profiles configured in advance, but for me this works. You can also use `-SelectProfile` to see existing profiles.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create another profile in firefox  and start another instance using -no-remote option.

---

I tried in Cent Os 6.5

Run this command in Command Terminal : firefox -p -no-remote

The Firefox profile manager will open up and will ask you to choose the profile you want to use. If you already have more than 1 profile, click on the “Create Profile” button to create a new profile and once the new profile is created, select it and click “Start Firefox”